# "it is suitable for employees who don't want responsibilities"

Tags: grammatical-number

"responsibilities" is marked wrong. In general, I am having problem determing when to use plural and when to use singular form of a word. Any help is greatly apprciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is about a test, perhaps a multiple choice test where you had to choose between singular and plural.  The trouble with the question is that it would depend on the context of the question.  The problem here lies in way in which in English (and many other languages) abstract nouns (like 'responsibility') can apply to the IDEA of having roles or tasks for which one is 'responsible' (ie in charge and accountable for outcomes involving other people) and such an individual task.  The idea 'responsibility' is singular only.  But the individual instances of it can be singular or plural.

So if a person does not want *responsibility* (the general idea), then s/he does not want *responsibilities* (any responsibilities at all).  You can say the same sort of thing about *friendship*.  If you are not good at *friendship*, then none of your actual *friendships* will have gone very well, or at least you haven't managed to have that many of them.

Only practice and experience will tell you when you can and when you can not. The best rule of thumb for tests that I can offer is to keep on the safe side and use the singular unless it is obvious that some specific (plural) instances are being referred to.